# Remove "Inbox." prefix from IMAP folders

Tags: thunderbird, android, imap

I've got a hosted website (Linux and cPanel apparently) - their support is slow, and I know the answer here will be better...

I've got an IMAP account set up, which I access from Thunderbird, an Android client, and the Horde webmail interface.

At present, it's set up so that the sent folder is "INBOX.Sent Items" and I've got "INBOX.Trash"; I'd like to re-arrange the folders so that it's just "Sent" (not a subfolder of Inbox).  (The Android client is good, but [has a bug which doesn't like "INBOX." prefixes](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1811)).

How do I rename my Sent and Trash folders to remove this prefix? In Horde I'm not given the option to remove it, and can't find any option to rename in Thunderbird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your email client doesn't support renaming you can always try [telnet](http://web.archive.org/web/20120611083131/http://bobpeers.com/technical/telnet_imap#create)

Comment: Thanks for this link! It appears I'm asking the wrong question, as it says: "The way IMAP works means that all folders are created as subfolders of the INBOX even if your email client is configured not to show it that way.", so my setup is correct. As webmail and Thunderbird are working just fine, I'll investigate how I can fix the Android client.

Comment: content linked to no longer exists.